Task watchdog got triggered. The following tasks did not reset the watchdog in time?
 task_wdt: Task watchdog got triggered. The following tasks did not reset the watchdog in time:
E (25603) task_wdt:  - loopTask (CPU 1)
E (25603) task_wdt: Tasks currently running:
E (25603) task_wdt: CPU 0: Task1
E (25603) task_wdt: CPU 1: loopTask
E (25603) task_wdt: Aborting.

abort() was called at PC 0x400dfab9 on core 0

Backtrace: 0x400836ad:0x3ffbec3c |<-CORRUPTED

ELF file SHA256: fde7bf06d933983a

Rebooting...

I'm getting this error and I don't know where I'm going wrong
Here is my code:
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <esp_task_wdt.h>

#include <RfidManager.h>
#include <DisplayManager.h>
#include <EspNowSender.h>
#include <BLESlave.h>



// const uint8_t receiverAddress[] = {0x88, 0x13, 0xBF, 0x24, 0xBD, 0x98};

RfidManager rfidManager;
DisplayManager displayManager;
EspNowSender espSender;
BLESlave bleSlave;

WiFiMulti wifiMulti;

uint8_t broadcastAddress[] = {0x88, 0x13, 0xBF, 0x24, 0xDB, 0x98};

typedef struct struct_pilot {
    int id;
    int x;
    int y;
} struct_pilot;

struct_pilot myPilot;
esp_now_peer_info_t peerInfo;

void OnDataSent(const uint8_t *mac_addr, esp_now_send_status_t status) {
  Serial.print("\r\nLast Packet Send Status:\t");
  Serial.println(status == ESP_NOW_SEND_SUCCESS ? "Delivery Success" : "Delivery Fail");
}

void sendDataTask(void *parameter) {
  for (;;) {
    myPilot.id = 2;
    if(digitalRead(15) == 0){
        myPilot.x = 0;
    }
    if(digitalRead(4) == 0){
        myPilot.x = 0;
    }
    if(digitalRead(13) == 0){
        myPilot.x = 0;
    }
    if(digitalRead(12) == 0){
        myPilot.x = 1;
    }
    if(digitalRead(14) == 0){
        myPilot.x = 1;
    }
    myPilot.y = random(0,50);

    esp_err_t result = esp_now_send(broadcastAddress, (uint8_t *) &myPilot, sizeof(myPilot));
    if (result == ESP_OK) {
      Serial.println("Sent with success");
    } else {
      Serial.println("Error sending the data");
    }

    vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(2000)); // Delay for 2 seconds
  }
}
void Task1(void *pvParameters);// This rfid task
void Task2(void *pvParameters);// This display task


void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    wifiMulti.addAP("Nang Luong Xanh", "nangluongxanh360");
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi...");
    while (wifiMulti.run() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        Serial.print(".");
        delay(100);
    }
    Serial.println("\nConnected to WiFi");

    WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);

    // Initialize ESP-NOW
    if (esp_now_init() != ESP_OK) {
        Serial.println("Error initializing ESP-NOW");
        return;
    }

    esp_now_register_send_cb(OnDataSent);

    memcpy(peerInfo.peer_addr, broadcastAddress, 6);
    peerInfo.channel = 0;
    peerInfo.encrypt = false;

    if (esp_now_add_peer(&peerInfo) != ESP_OK) {
        Serial.println("Failed to add peer");
        return;
    }


    esp_task_wdt_init(15, true); // Tăng thời gian timeout lên 15 giây
    esp_task_wdt_add(NULL); // Thêm task hiện tại (main task) vào WDT

    xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(
      Task1, "Task1", 2048, NULL, 2, NULL, 0); //rfid task
    xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(
      Task2, "Task2", 2048, NULL, 1, NULL, 1);; //display task
    xTaskCreate(sendDataTask, "Send Data Task", 2048, NULL, 1, NULL);
}

void loop() {
  
}


void Task1(void *pvParameters)  // This is a task.
{
    rfidManager.RfidManagerSetup();
    esp_task_wdt_add(NULL); // Thêm Task1 vào WDT
    for(;;)
    {
        rfidManager.RfidManagerloop();
        esp_task_wdt_reset(); // Reset watchdog
        vTaskDelay(100 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS); // Giảm thời gian delay
    }
}


void Task2(void *pvParameters)  // This is a task.
{
    displayManager.DisplayManagerSetup();
    esp_task_wdt_add(NULL); // Thêm Task2 vào WDT

    for(;;)
    {
        displayManager.DisplayManagerloop();

        
        esp_task_wdt_reset(); // Reset watchdog
        vTaskDelay(500 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS); // Giảm thời gian delay
    }
}






esp_task_wdt_init A 15 second timeout does not make any sense. In most systems having a 1 second timeout is already way too much. And then according to the Friendly Manual, if the second parameter is true, then a "panic handler" will be executed. How that makes sense, I have no idea, but I guess this is some early warning executed before the watchdog timeouts? Or otherwise the lib isn't making any sense.

Why do you call esp_task_wdt_add(NULL); in setup if you don't plan to reset the WDT in your loop function?

Assuming, that loopTask refers to the task that calls function loop(), I think you have to reset the watchdog inside loop().
See e.g. https://iotassistant.io/esp32/enable-hardware-watchdog-timer-esp32-arduino-ide/
Example code copied from this site:
#include <esp_task_wdt.h>

//3 seconds WDT
#define WDT_TIMEOUT 3

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Configuring WDT...");
  esp_task_wdt_init(WDT_TIMEOUT, true); //enable panic so ESP32 restarts
  esp_task_wdt_add(NULL); //add current thread to WDT watch

}

int i = 0;
int last = millis();

void loop() {
  // resetting WDT every 2s, 5 times only
  if (millis() - last >= 2000 && i < 5) {
      Serial.println("Resetting WDT...");
      esp_task_wdt_reset();
      last = millis();
      i++;
      if (i == 5) {
        Serial.println("Stopping WDT reset. CPU should reboot in 3s");
      }
  }
}

I did not test this solution.
According to romkey's comment, resetting the watchdog from loop() should not be necessary.
I think, this depends on the circumstances.
Citing an arduino forum thread:

There's no need to call esp_task_wdt_reset from loop. That is already
done in the wrapper in main.cpp that calls setup and loop
[...]
as long as you call enableLoopWDT from setup, which both calls
esp_task_wdt_add for you and sets that loopTaskWDTEnabled variable to
true.

If you call esp_task_wdt_add instead of enableLoopWDT from setup, you might have to call esp_task_wdt_add yourself from loop.

The Arduino Core automatically resets the wdt when loop() returns… if it didn’t, Arduino programs would crash with a wdt exception almost immediately.

@romkey see my edit
